# Parallel testing in Selenium with Telerik Kendo UI and screenshots subscribed to WebDriver events

Tags: c#, selenium, kendo-ui, webdriver, screenshot

The issue is related to Kendo UI's (dropdownlist, combobox, searchbox, etc) `onfocusout` and `blur` events, which close menu dropdowns when triggered, or if a browser window loses focus. In my case it was the WebDriver's `GetScreenshot()` method which calls an active focus on a screenshotted browser. With the parallel testing I'm taking screenshots using `EventFiringWebDriver` events. There are two windows of Edge/Chrome browser running in parallel and they are flashing constantly since `GetScreenshot()` is triggered. If Kendo UI element is opened in one of the windows, and the moment when flashing happens at the same time, it automatically triggers `onfocusout` and `blur` and dropdown closes. 40% of my tests were false negative because of that.

You can see the demo of the elements here: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome the issue with a multi-step solution. This works on Edge/Chrome 103+ and Selenium 4.1+

**Firstly**, I got rid of active focus calling by overring the `GetScreenshot()` method with a direct command to WebDriver.

```
public Screenshot GetScreenshot()
    {
        IHasCommandExecutor executor = Driver as IHasCommandExecutor;
        var sessionId = ((WebDriver)Driver).SessionId; //if your driver is wrapped by any other class, you have to cast it to WebDriver first
        var command = new HttpCommandInfo(HttpCommandInfo.PostCommand, $"/session/{sessionId}/chromium/send_command_and_get_result");
        executor.CommandExecutor.TryAddCommand("Send", command); //try to create and add a command

        var response = Send(executor, "Page.captureScreenshot", new JObject { { "format", "png" }, { "fromSurface", true } });
        var base64 = ((Dictionary<string, object>)response.Value)["data"];
        return new Screenshot(base64.ToString());
    }

    private Response Send(IHasCommandExecutor executor, string cmd, JObject args)
    {         
        var json = new JObject { { "cmd", cmd }, { "params", args } }; 
        var command = new Command("Send", json.ToString());
        return executor.CommandExecutor.Execute(command); //execute the added command
    }
```

**Secondly**, I found an extension for Chromium browsers, which disables Visibility API. There are a bunch of them, just search "Disable Visibility API" in Chrome Web Store. Apparently, it fakes 'activeness' of a browser window, so `onfocusout` and `blur` won't be firing anymore. Now you just have to include the extension when you're instantiating your driver:

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddExtension("your path to extension"); //set your path
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new EdgeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
Driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```